# Isn't the set of all literature a regular language?

Tags: regular-language

Let one piece of literature be one string.  Let's define our alphabet to be sufficient to represent all literature (e.g. we may need a page-turn character, etc).  So, since the collection of current literature is finite, it is a regular language.  However, we usually talk about such languages as context sensitive and natural which are harder for a computer to deal with.  So, what am I missing here?

Thanks.

Comment: BTW, there is a way to include 2-D formulae: convert it to LaTeX or treat it as a generalized grammar (two or more concatenation points on each character in the language).

Comment: When people talk about natural language, they're not talking about the existing corpus of natural language, but I suppose the _potential_ corpus of natural language.

Comment: To illustrate Qiaochu's point, ['I can say the following sentence and be utterly sure that nobody has ever said it before in the history of human communication: "Hold the newsreader's nose squarely, waiter, or friendly milk will countermand my trousers."'](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hHQ2756cyD8)

Comment: It's also concerned with existing stuff.  e.g.  Computer, draw a circle.  That's easy to interpret if that's all you want the computer to do, but if you add in a bunch of other requirements like it must interpret all ways to say draw a circle or draw an elementary 2D shape using language X, graphics API Y, position R, and only do it in certain contexts, then it's much harder.  But I see your guys' points.  :D

Comment: Whether natural language is regular or not is just a small part of how problematic it is "for computers to deal with". The classical example: Compare *Time flies like an arrow* to *Fruit flies like a banana*. Structurally they are identical, and it's hard to imagine a computer program being able to distinguish them without lots and lots of contextual "knowledge".

Comment: Especially since humans are not reliably able to parse this kind of sentences after each other.